# How can we ignore the diverging term $e^\infty$ in the integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, integration

In [Question (2.20)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fcEe.jpg) of Griffiths' Quantum Mechanics book, they have given this [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leV5I.jpg).

In the Solution of question 2.20(b), they omitted $e^{(ik-a) \infty}$ (or may have considered $e^{(ik-a) \infty}=0$) in this calculation

[image: calculation of 2.20(b)].

How can it be correct at all?

Comment: That’s not $e^{\infty}$, it’s $e^{-\infty}$ which is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite the indefinite integral as
\begin{equation}
e^{-a x} f(x)
\end{equation}
where $f(x)$ does not grow exponentially with $x$. (In fact $f(x) \sim e^{\pm i k x}$ is an oscillating function).

In the limit $x\rightarrow \infty$, we have that $e^{-a x} f(x) \rightarrow 0$, since $e^{-ax} \rightarrow 0$ and $f(x)$ doesn't grow fast enough to cancel this behavior. This assumes ${\rm Re}( a )> 0$.

Comment: Another way of saying this is that $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$, is that  makes the integral absolutely convergent, so we can treat it as just a Riemann integral. Then, the bracket at the end is : $$\left[\frac{e^{(ik-a)x}}{ik-a}\right]_0^\infty= \left(\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{e^{(ik-a)x}}{ik-a}\right)- \frac{1}{ik-a} = -\frac{1}{ik-a}$$ because $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{(ik-a)x} = 0$